# Retrieve key from osx keychain

Tags: swift, pointers, keychain

I am trying to retrieve my app's secret key from the keychain such that it can be used to authenticate with the server. I have successfully stored it there but cannot get it back.

```
func getClientKey(){
    let keyValptr:UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>?
    let lenPtr:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>? = UInt32(13) //how do i do this?
    _ = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(nil,
        UInt32(serviceName.characters.count), serviceName, 
        UInt32(accountName.characters.count), accountName, 
        lenPtr, keyValptr, nil)

    print(keyValptr)
 }
```

I've commented the line I'm having issues with. How do i obtain a correct pointer to pass into the function? It wants a `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>?` (where I would choose what the value actually is)

Comment: `var len: UInt32 = 13` and then pass `&len` to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you want to pass `UnsafeMutablePoiner<T>?` (or `UnsafeMutablePoiner<T>`), you declare a variable of type `T` (not a pointer to `T`) and pass it as an inout parameter (prefix `&`).

So, specific to your issue, your way of passing `keyValPtr` is also wrong.

For the parameter `passwordLength: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>?`, you need to declare a variable of type `UInt32`.
And for `passwordData: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>?`, you need to declare a variable of type `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`.

And, unfortunately in many cases this may not be a critical issue, you need to calculate length based on UTF-8 representation, when passing Swift `String` directly to `UnsafePointer<Int8>?`.

You may need to write something like this:

```
func getClientKey() {
    var keyVal: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = nil
    var len: UInt32 = 13 //<- this value is ignored though...
    let status = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
        nil,
        UInt32(serviceName.utf8.count), serviceName, //### Use `utf8.count`
        UInt32(accountName.utf8.count), accountName, //### Use `utf8.count`
        &len,       //### to pass `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>?`, declare a variable of `UInt32`.
        &keyVal,    //### to pass `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>?`, declare a variable of `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`.
        nil
    )

    if status == noErr {
        let keyData = Data(bytes: keyVal!, count: Int(len))
        //### As noted in the API reference of `SecKeychainFindGenericPassword`,
        // "You should use the SecKeychainItemFreeContent function to free the memory pointed to by this parameter."
        SecKeychainItemFreeContent(nil, keyVal)

        print(keyData as NSData)
        print(String(data: keyData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "?")
    } else {
        //You should not silently ignore erros...
        print("Error: \(status)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost answered my search for how to extract the password but where and how is Data declared?